Browser Not Saving HttpOnly Cookie React/Django
I have a netlify frontend at app.mydomain.com, and a django ninja REST API at api.mydomain.com. When I submit to my login endpoint, the api returns successfully with the access key (which I store in app state) and a refresh token in the form of a secure, httponly cookie. I can see this cookie is returned by looking in the response headers in dev tools. The cookie however is not stored by the browser at all, I've gone through numerous other questions/answers and I believe I have implemented everything required, but it's still not working.
My login API call from the frontend is:
await fetch(
  AUTH_URL_OBTAIN,
  {
    method: RequestMethod.POST,
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    body: JSON.stringify({username: formData.email, password: formData.password}),
    credentials: "include",
  },
);

On the backend, the cookie is set like this:
response.set_cookie(
    key="refresh",
    value=refresh_token,
    expires=datetime.fromtimestamp(refresh_token_payload["exp"], timezone.utc),
    httponly=True,
    samesite="none",
    secure=True,
    path="/api/auth/web/token-refresh",
    domain=".mydomain.com",
)

I also have the following settings set (substituting the values in for environment variables):
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://app.mydomain.com"]
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["https://app.mydomain.com"]
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ["https://app.mydomain.com"]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True


The login response provides the access token (which works as expected - I am able to make API calls using this just fine, and have credentials: include on all fetch requests) and the response headers are below:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://app.mydomain.com

Content-Length: 661

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin

Date: Thu, 06 Jun 2024 14:06:22 GMT

Referrer-Policy: same-origin

Server: daphne

Set-Cookie: refresh=ey...3uQ; Domain=.mydomain.com; expires=Sat, 06 Jul 2024 14:06:22 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=2592000; Path=/api/auth/web/token-refresh; SameSite=none; Secure

Vary: origin

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

X-Frame-Options: DENY

I'm at a bit of a loss at this point - any advice would be very appreciated, thank you!

just curious, what happen if you don't include the HttpOnly (just set normal cookie), does it work? My hunch is that it might not be caused by the HttpOnly

Have you tried adding maxAge to the cookie response and also sameSite: "lax" and check

Hi, thanks for your comments. @Damzaky yeah you're right, other cookies are being set ok. The sessionid cookie seems to be set which is httponly. The csrftoken cookie is also set which is not httponly. The refresh cookie is still not set.
@TarunKantiwal the max age is set and I have tried all variations for samesite.

hmm that's odd, what about changing the cookie key name from refresh to something else like refreshone?

I gave that a try too and it's still not saving. I can see the cookie in the response, and the browser isn't showing any errors, but it's just not saving in the cookie. I've tried on safari too and it doesn't work on there either.

I'm not sure, but maybe you should try with an expiry date in the future ?

Is the access token also set as a Cookie? Are you setting the access token exactly the same way and it works but refresh doesn’t work?

There are some points you should check: 1. Path=/api/auth/web/token-refresh: the cookie will be saved for this path only. 2. Secure: the cookie will only be set on https 3.expires: you should remove it in favor of max-age 4.Domain=.mydomain.com: the cookie will be accessible for subdomain only

Hi everyone, thanks for all the comments, really appreciate all the help. franckfournier, yeah the expiry date is set to a future date, the example I posted above was for the cookie set on that day.
ChukwujiobiCanon, the access token is stored in app state - I think I might just have to store the refresh token in app state too maybe?
Duannx, thanks for that checklist, I'll go through it today and report back!

@Duannx I think you cracked it!! I changed the Path to just / and the refresh cookie is being set now! I am a bit confused though, why would the browser not be setting the cookie when the path is set to the full refresh endpoint?
If you want to post your suggestion of checking the path as an answer I'll accept + bounty!

It has nothing to do with either Django or React. It is the way how you set the cookie.

A cookie with a path can be set anywhere but accessible only on that path and its child. So you can only see the cookie when visiting the page /api/auth/web/token-refresh
Consider using Max-Age over Expires since it is less error-prone. This is the quote from MDN page:


Expires has been available for longer than Max-Age, however Max-Age is less error-prone, and takes precedence when both are set. The rationale behind this is that when you set an Expires date and time, they're relative to the client the cookie is being set on. If the server is set to a different time, this could cause errors.


Secure cookie can only be set through https or localhost


Been waiting for an answer from you.

Thanks again for the help, setting the path to / in the end did the trick, also really interesting info on the Max-Age/Expires data too. Cheers!

You're welcome ;-)

Browser security policies can block cookies from/to ajax requests. See

Firefox not sending cookie in Ajax request (XMLHttpRequest)
Does Axios support Set-Cookie? Is it possible to authenticate through Axios HTTP request?

For a cross-origin API, I'd rather not use cookies at all. Imagine any API client other than a browser! Cookies are meant to track browsing sessions in a website, not storing state in arbitrary http clients.
Just include the refresh token in the response body and store it in your app state as well.

Hi, thanks a lot for your answer! If I do this, and the user refreshes the page, they'll lose all the tokens meaning they'd have to log in again right? Not the end of the world if that's what it takes to be secure here, just want to make sure I fully understand this as a potential solution.

I've implemented many solutions of this type, where the cookie is used to enable an API message credential and is hence issued on the API side of the architecture.
It looks to me like your problem is the expires property of the cookie. This causes the cookie to be persistent and I expect it is set incorrectly. Everything else looks right.
I think you might fix your problem if you remove that cookie property. Doing do is also a security best practice and results in a session cookie that is removed when the browser is closed.
Also, it is not portable to make assumptions about refresh token formats or payloads. Instead, a refresh token is considered expired when you try to use it at the authorization server's token emdpoint and receive a response with an invalid_grant error code. Therefore, when using cookies that represent tokens, always derive expiry from the underlying token.
